# Is there any way to exit from the RS3 client in just 1 click?

Tags: technical-issues, runescape

Is there any way to be able to exit the Runescape 3 client while logged on in just 1 click? I cannot seem to find an answer on Google, Reddit, or this site.

Currently, when I try to exit the client either by logging out, or even if I hit the X button in the top-right corner or if I alt+F4, it still asks me for confirmation if I'm sure I want to close the game. I would like to be able to immediately close the game by exiting the client without it asking for confirmation. Does anyone know of a way to bypass/turn off this feature of the client?

EDIT: alternatively, is there a way to make a preference for going to lobby vs. logging out using the "door" logout button so I can perform either action in a single click?

Comment: Why do you want this capability?

Comment: I am not sure why my intent is relevant, but...

1. if I am lagging or there is a connection issue so I can immediately exit and reload the client.
2. If I am in the wilderness and encounter a potential threat I'd like to be able to log out as fast as possible.

Comment: Can see the use for the Wilds thing. But I'm pretty sure that you are still logged in for a few seconds in the server when you log out. So I don't think it would save you.

Comment: When I press the X in the top right, it closes immediately, no prompts.  I could of swore it use to ask me however.  That being said, "X Logging" as it's called can be iffy.  I think if you are in combat when you do it, your account stays logged in until you are out of combat (whether that means you died or you killed whatever you are fighting).  Far as I can tell, there is no 1 click exit besides X Logging (which for me doesn't seem to have a prompt anymore).  The fastest way is probably pressing Escape and then either choosing exit to lobby or logout.

Comment: What @Timmy Jim said is correct as far as the combat thing when you X Log. So being in the wild and doing that is probably not a good idea. There is no way to change these settings in the RS3 client.

Comment: Quitting out of the game does not necessarily log you out. I believe if you are in combat you can leave the game, but your `session` will still be active.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little barbaric, but Open task manager with Ctrl+Shift+Esc, keep it behind Runescape.

When you want to leave, Alt+Tab, and End process. Should close it right away, skipping the confirmation box.

Alt+F4 is asking nicely for your program to close. This is more like drop everything and just close. It wont try to save it's progress or stuff like that. But for an always online thing like runescape it should be ok.

Comment: That's no faster than just clicking confirm.

Comment: It's that or having a script, bind it to a macro, that shuts down the process when pressed. But I don't know how to program that.

Pretty sure it's possible to do tho.

Comment: Might be a question for SuperUser at that point

Answer (score 0):

I believe they updated the client so that when you now press the X to close the client, initially it has a prompt asking to confirm you wish to close the client, but if you tick the box below saying 'Do not ask again' then it will close instantly every time thereafter.